# Same xml but different dialog result in Gingerbrad and ICS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

This is my question:
I have an xml file that describes the layout for a custom dialog in my app.
Running it on two AVD with Gingerbread 2.3.3 and ICS 4.0.3 the dialog seems to appear "normal" on GB and "too small" on ICS.!!
I cant understand why this is happening.
[Link to image](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/2296/immagineoun.png)
My xml code is: `

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Aggiungi una nuova Spesa!"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
 />
 <ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dim_dark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/edittOggetto" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="Inserisci l'oggetto..."
     android:paddingTop="5dip"/>         

 <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/edittPrezzo" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="numberDecimal"
     android:hint="Inserisci il prezzo..."/> 

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textvSelezionaCategoria"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="16dip"
           android:paddingLeft="5dip"
           android:paddingBottom="4.0dip"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:text="Categoria"/>
        <Spinner 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
           android:id="@+id/spinner_categoria"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textvFontePagamento"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="16dip"
           android:paddingLeft="5dip"
           android:paddingBottom="4.0dip"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:text="Pagamento "/>
        <Spinner 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
           android:id="@+id/spinner_aggsp"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textvDataOraAggiungiSpesa"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Data: "/>    
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip">
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/calendarioSmall"
        android:layout_width="20dip" 
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/calendario_small"
        android:clickable="false"/>
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textvCambiaData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dip"       
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Modifica\n Data"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"/>       
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/timeSmall"
        android:layout_width="20dip" 
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/time_small"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textvCambiaOra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dip"        
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:text="Modifica\n Ora"/>   
 </LinearLayout> 
 <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" 
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">      
        <Button 
               android:id="@+id/btnAggiungiOggetto"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Aggiungi"
               android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
        <Button 
              android:id="@+id/btnAnnullaOggetto"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Annulla"
              android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

`

In my activity i call the dialog in this way:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);        
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogaggiungispesa); 
 ...
 dialog.show();
```

How can I resolve this problem? I would like to have the same dialog layout on every version of android.
Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Are you sure it's the OS version that's causing this? Are the AVDs different densities?

Comment: No the AVDs have the same densities. I have this problem also on my Samsung Galaxy S.